# Align check box below the label?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code for a check box:

```
<td class="myClass">
    select<br><input type="checkbox" id="one" name="delete" value="one">
</td>
```

Its output is as below:

[image]

but I want the checkbox to be displayed exactly below the label, like so:

```
     select
       []
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add style `text-align:center;` and `display:block;` to the container.

**Good tip:** (maybe you know it) If the container of the label and checkbox wll be `<label>`, the input share click event with the container. For examle:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="myClass">
      <label>
        Click me, to change Checkbox value !<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="one" name="delete" value="one" align="">
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

check it out http://jsfiddle.net/G7JxA/

Answer (score 0):

Add a `span` tag around the text, then assign a width and `text-align:center` to both the `span` and `input`.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="myClass">
        <span>select<span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="one" name="delete" value="one"/>
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.myClass{
    width: 40px;
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/GSRGX/

Comment: Woudn't `<label>` be more appropriate to wrap the text with?

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jVpT7/)**

Please check above `demo.`

`.myClass` gives `text-align:center;`

```
<table>
    <tr>
<td class="myClass">
    select<br><input type="checkbox" id="one" name="delete" value="one" align="">
</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you set position as relative for your checkbox, you can move it around with left:, right:, top:, bottom:.

The html code would look like this:

```
<td class="myClass">
    select
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="one" name="delete" value="one" />
</td>
```

And the css:

```
#one {
position:relative;
left:12px;
}
```

I have made a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/horduringi/SydBA/).