# Centering a MDL-checkbox with css

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

I am trying to create a table with mdl where the user can check certain weekdays. For that, I want to have checkboxes with the label centered below them. For normal html I already found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18142574/12288557). For the mdl-checkbox, this does not work, see the example. So far, I can only manage to center the label, but not the mdl-checkbox itself. Any suggestions as to how I can center both?

```css
.myClass label{
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.amber-indigo.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  
        <div class="myClass">
          <label>            
            <input type="checkbox" id="one">
            <br>This works
          </label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="myClass">
         <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox-th">
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-th" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
          <br>This doesn't
         </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: it uses span on absolute position and piled on top of each others, use mdl as it is supposed too or use another method to customize your checkboxes. To keep mdl customized checkboxes in the flow requires to rewrite the code. probably a library build by a develloper, not a front-end designer ;)

Comment: "as it is supposed to" - You mean mdl is not supposed to center checkboxes? Finding another method is exactly why I ask that question.

Comment: look for fancy checkbox or any similar keywords on the forum .

Comment: here is an example of fancy checboxes https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JkDoK connected to radio input actually. it uses a span to draw a fake input